# Box Collider on terrain trees activate far from the actual collider

Tags: unity, collider

The trees are prefabs but are placed as terrain trees. There is a space ship that explodes when hits the tree. The moment I got the screenshot is the moment that the ship collides with terrain (the tree). However, there is a giant gap between the tree and the ship and as you can see in the prefab, the colliders are not there yet.

This issue does not happen when the tree is placed as a prefab directly in the scene.

[image: collision moment]
[image: tree collider]

Comment: It sounds like the issue is related to the collider of the tree not being positioned correctly when the tree is placed as a terrain tree.

Comment: Is there a way to see terrain colliders?